# How to Send Mail Using AWS SES Without verify Receiver Email Id?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, sendmail, amazon-ses

Actually, I want to send bulk email using Amazone SES and I was stuck in verification of Receiver's Email Addresses.

So, can you ple.showing us the way how we can do it us without verifying the Receivers Email Id's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new account in SES, it goes to something called `sandbox` account which requires recipient email address verification.

You can submit a support ticket to get your account out of `sandbox`. Once you are not in `sandbox` account, you will not be required to verify recipient email addresses.

You can view the documentation to get your account out of `sandbox` at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html